# OpenCV Stereo Calibration Matrix Error

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, camera-calibration, stereoscopy

I'm trying to calibrate a stereo camera using OpenCV 2.4.9, and I'm running into an error when I call `stereoCalibrate`.

Below are the images I'm using. (with some weird coloring glitches courtesy of MS Paint). The three images on the top are from the left camera and the three on bottom are from the right camera. Note that I have use a few more image pairs, and the images aren't actually this small, they are 640x480; however, I shrunk them and omitted some so that this post isn't 935837 miles long.

Example Input Images:
[image: Example Calibration Images.png]

OpenCV finds the chessboard corners just fine. I display them using `drawChessboardCorners`, and they look right. So that's not the problem.

I then calibrate each camera separately using `calibrateCamera`. I display images that are passed though `undistort` using the matrices using `calibrateCamera`, and the result seems to over-correct just a little for the lens distortion.

Undistorted based on the output of `calibrateCamera`:
[image: Undistorted based on output of calibrateCamera]

The same error occurs if I omit the `calibrateCamera` step and adjust the flags of `stereoCalibrate` accordingly (replace the `CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC` flag with `CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH | CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST`)

Next I call `stereoCalibrate`, and I get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims == 2 && (sizes[0] == 1 || sizes[1] == 1 || sizes[0]*sizes[1] == 0))
in create, file c:/Users/s-foxk/Documents/libs/opencv/sources/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1564

...Generic Widnows Garbage...

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  c:/Users/s-foxk/Documents/libs/opencv/sources/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1564:
error: (-215) dims == 2 && (sizes[0] == 1 || sizes[1] == 1 || sizes[0]*sizes[1] == 0) in function create
```

For the past several hours, I have searched for a solution to this problem, and for information about this error, as well as changing little bits of my code. All, unfortunately, to no avail. There seems to be very little information about this error or maybe just this situation.

What does this error mean? How can I get rid of it? It has occurred to me that the chessboard may be too far away, given the 640x480 resolution of the camera. Could this be the issue?

If anyone wishes to see part or all of my code, I will gladly create a pastebin for it, but I hesitate to dump it here, since it is long and ugly.